# Visual Studio Community Edition and Fakes Framework?

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-fakes

I can't see the "Add Fakes Assembly" item in my test project's references' shortcut menu. Is Microsoft Fakes Framework available in Visual Studio Community 2013 edition?

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft Fakes is not available in Professional Edition. Therefore, it won't appear in Community Edition either (but you can let your voice be heard).

[Reference](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/371113/add-microsoft-fakes-unit-test-isolation-to-profess.html)